# How to split a dataframe into two based on the column data type

Tags: python

My original dataframe is df. I want to split to two df based on the data type. Numbers(Int64, float64) and Strings(object)

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df.dtypes[col] == np.object:
        df1[col] = df[col]
    else:
        df2[col] = df[col]
df1.to_excel('str.xlsx')
df2.to_excel('num.xlsx')
```

Comment: Just wondering whether it is the most efficient way to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Panda select_dtypes function

```
df_num = df.select_dtypes(include='int64')
    
df_Strings = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
```